# What assembly(s) contain all the MonoTouch binding attributes used by btouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, custom-attributes

I'm trying to get intellisense working in MonoDevelop when writing an ObjC binding project. To do this the IDE needs to know where the various binding attributes exist.

e.g:
`[ExportAttribute]` seems to live in monotouch.dll (`MonoTouch.Foundation` namespace).
`[LinkWithAttribute]` is also in monotouch.dll (but `MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime` namespace).

However I can't find the more specialized attributes anywhere (`EventArgsAttibute`, `EventNameAttribute`, etc). See the full list documented here: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types/Binding_Types_Reference_Guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those attributes live in the [binding compiler itself](https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/1791e660c08a509d6a49efcb5791f6710be9a29c/src/generator.cs) (i.e. `/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/btouch/btouch.exe`).

They're used to give `btouch` instructions on what kind of code to emit while it builds the bindings assembly; they're *not* used by the runtime, and, thus, don't have to be included in any of the MonoTouch runtime assemblies.

I guess for purposes of getting IntelliSense working, you might as well just include a reference to btouch.exe.